# NextJS Use 'import' with ESM packages instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, es6-modules

I'm getting this error:

```
Module not found: ESM packages (remark) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals
  2 | import path from 'path'
  3 | //import matter from 'gray-matter'
> 4 | import remark from 'remark'
    |                           ^
  5 | import html from 'remark-html'
```

Even though the module is being imported correctly.

When I change it to a name which doesn't exist I get:

```
./lib/posts.js:4:28
Module not found: Can't resolve 'remarke'
  2 | import path from 'path'
  3 | //import matter from 'gray-matter'
> 4 | import remark from 'remarke'
    |                            ^
  5 | import html from 'remark-html'
```

So I know that it is imported.

I also tried adding this to next.config.js:

```
experimental: {
        esmExternals: "loose",
    },
```

But then I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _remark).default is not a function
```

This has something to do with the switch to ESM module of the remark library.

Does anyone know what I can do to get rid of this error?